# QGIS dissolve/merge features by all attributes

Tags: qgis-3, dissolve

I have a vector layer with thousands of features and over ten columns (attributes). I would like to dissolve/merge features with identical attribute combinations and keep the attributes. I think it could be "singleparts to multiparts" but I can´t find this in the toolbox. In dissolve by attribute it is only possible for three attributes. I remember that I did it very easy one day...

Comment: I think the tool has been renamed to `Promote to multipart`.

Comment: You could create a field combining all the attribute you need and dissolve on this field

Comment: thank you, I found the tool